# Foreign key constraints missing from SHOW CREATE TABLE output

Tags: mysql

I'm finding that `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is not showing foreign key constraints as I would expect.

To demonstrate, here’s an example from the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE child (
  id INT, parent_id INT,
  INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE child\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: child
Create Table: CREATE TABLE "child" (
  "id" int(11) default NULL,
  "parent_id" int(11) default NULL,
  KEY "par_ind" ("parent_id")
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In that output I would have expected to see something like:

```
CONSTRAINT `child_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`)
REFERENCES `parent` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

in that create table output but clearly it's not there.

The constraint does however appear to exist:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE table_schema=database()\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           CONSTRAINT_CATALOG: NULL
            CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA: test_fk
              CONSTRAINT_NAME: child_ibfk_1
                TABLE_CATALOG: NULL
                 TABLE_SCHEMA: test_fk
                   TABLE_NAME: child
                  COLUMN_NAME: parent_id
             ORDINAL_POSITION: 1
POSITION_IN_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT: 1
      REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA: test_fk
        REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME: parent
       REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME: id
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           CONSTRAINT_CATALOG: NULL
            CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA: test_fk
              CONSTRAINT_NAME: PRIMARY
                TABLE_CATALOG: NULL
                 TABLE_SCHEMA: test_fk
                   TABLE_NAME: parent
                  COLUMN_NAME: id
             ORDINAL_POSITION: 1
POSITION_IN_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT: NULL
      REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA: NULL
        REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME: NULL
       REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME: NULL
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE table_schema=database()\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
CONSTRAINT_CATALOG: NULL
 CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA: test_fk
   CONSTRAINT_NAME: child_ibfk_1
      TABLE_SCHEMA: test_fk
        TABLE_NAME: child
   CONSTRAINT_TYPE: FOREIGN KEY
*************************** 2. row ***************************
CONSTRAINT_CATALOG: NULL
 CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA: test_fk
   CONSTRAINT_NAME: PRIMARY
      TABLE_SCHEMA: test_fk
        TABLE_NAME: parent
   CONSTRAINT_TYPE: PRIMARY KEY
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I get the same results with examples of my own design.

Any idea what's going on?

---

**UPDATE 2011-01-08**: I think this has something to do with the sql_mode variable. But at the moment I don't know which mode setting excludes constraints from SHOW CREATE TABLE output.

Comment: The constraint shows for me OK. Which `MySQL` version are you using? Aren't you getting the errors when creating the tables?

Answer (score 1):

The setting of the mysql sql_mode variable was definitely the cause of the behavior I reported. I deleted the line that set it from my.cnf and mysql performed the expected behavior. But I forget what that setting was and haven't figured it out since. If anyone can identify which, go right ahead.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately i can not comment as I wanted to to, so hear goes a weak answer to your question . . .

This command works ! when creating table try to implement foreign key with:
constraint and a name / id !

> CONSTRAINT 'child_fk1' FOREIGN KEY
>   ('parent_id') REFERENCES  parent('id')

may help, otherwise check oracle mysql syntax online corrsponding to your server version !!

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html
regards

Comment: emanind just set constarint correctly when creating table in the first place !

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this, this query will help:

```
SELECT tb1.CONSTRAINT_NAME, tb1.TABLE_NAME, tb1.COLUMN_NAME,
tb1.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, tb1.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME, tb2.MATCH_OPTION,
tb2.UPDATE_RULE, tb2.DELETE_RULE
FROM information_schema.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` AS tb1
INNER JOIN information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS tb2
ON tb1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tb2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE table_schema = '{DATABASE_NAME}'
AND referenced_column_name IS NOT NULL
```

Originally taken from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734331/constraint-detail-from-information-schema-on-update-cascade-on-delete-restrict)

Unfortunately changing 'sql_mode' in 'my.cnf' didn't have any effect on the output of:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE {TABLE_NAME};
```

It still did not show the 'ON DELETE' restriction. Used MySQL version 5.6.22 on Mac OS X 10.9.