# Constraint detail from information_schema (on update cascade, on delete restrict)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, information-schema

Almost all the information I had needed about a database, I  could find in information_schema

This time I needed to read details of **all foreign keys in a database through single query** I found every thing in information_schema.key_Column_usage but could not find the `constraints like on delete, on update`

I could do `show create table` for all individual tables. But is there any way to get these details through some select query like this?

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME, TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, 
REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` WHERE 
table_schema = 'mydbname' AND referenced_column_name IS NOT NULL
```

It is doing the job well but just missing constraints like `on delete, on update` How can I get those values as well so that I can get all info about foreign keys in a single query?

Comment: Have you tried the `extra` column?

Comment: @njk It does not exists in `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`.

Comment: It exists in columns table. I had tried it but now had a look again for these details but it just contains info about auto_increment and not any for these constraints

Comment: The documentation says there should be a table `information_schema.referential_constraints`. But I don't see it.

Comment: @Barmar I realize I'm late to the party, but I just checked and `referential_constraints` shows up on version 5.6.17 for me. The docs say it was added in 5.1.10, maybe you're/were using an older version?

Comment: @s.m. Looks like a case-sensitivity issue. The table is `REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`, I was looking for `referential_constraints`.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, sure, all the tables in information_schema are upper case, but since I'm using Navicat, it didn't make a difference to me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`UPDATE_RULE` and `DELETE_RULE` is the thing you asked for

it's a little bit too late but it could help someone else, here the solution :

```
SELECT tb1.CONSTRAINT_NAME, tb1.TABLE_NAME, tb1.COLUMN_NAME,
tb1.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, tb1.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME, tb2.MATCH_OPTION,

tb2.UPDATE_RULE, tb2.DELETE_RULE

FROM information_schema.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` AS tb1
INNER JOIN information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS tb2 ON
tb1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tb2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE table_schema = 'sfa' AND referenced_column_name IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Exactly what i asked and would be helpful for others

Comment: You should use "ON tb1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tb2.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND tb1.TABLE_SCHEMA = tb2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA AND tb1.TABLE_NAME = tb2.TABLE_NAME" for the JOIN as the constraint name is not unique

Answer (score 2):

**Update** From `information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` table **add in mysql 5.1** [mysql-5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.1/) we can get information about all constraints**. Accepted answer gives the solution as query.

**Earlier**
Before mysql 5.1 like [mysql-5.0](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.0/), we could not get this information, we could only use `show create table` for individual table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for (primary|foreign|unique) keys :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/table-constraints-table.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where far i know, `On delete and on update` are used with `foreign key constraints` e.g. `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Triggers have syntax like `BEFORE DELETE` or `AFTER UPDATE` and not `on update`. I am just looking for `ON UPDATE and ON DELETE` which are used with foreign keys as `referential integrity constraints`

Answer (score 0):

Now, you can find foreign key constraint details in table INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/referential-constraints-table.html