# Generic Admin Site in Php / Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am building a auto / generic client admin panel for Mysql Databases , it only takes a connection string and the system Dynamically creates all the The forms for all the tables with validation and Creates ALL CRUD operations  for the tables in the database , i finished all that and did it OOP but the last thing to do is get the tables and Fields Relations Dynamically , so how can i implement that ?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Look at the MySQL SHOW TABLES... and SHOW COLUMNS... statements.

If you're looking for foreign key constraints you can query [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/table-constraints-table.html) and [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/key-column-usage-table.html).

Comment: i did show columns from table and on of the Fields that i wont to see its relation after print_r i see this :    Array ( [0] => Brand_ID [Field] => Brand_ID [1] => int(11) [Type] => int(11) [2] => YES [Null] => YES [3] => MUL [Key] => MUL [4] => [Default] => [5] => [Extra] => )

Comment: I've added lins to the MySQL pages that cover the tables I referenced. There's a lot of info there. Take a look, and if it isn't what you need, come back.

Answer (score 0):

Both gonna help you out:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE table_schema='<database>' AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL
```

Prints you all foreign keys of a specified database.
Can easily be used for any case of working with your foreign keys.

Might also be helpful:
[Foreign key constraints missing from SHOW CREATE TABLE output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548472/foreign-key-constraints-missing-from-show-create-table-output)

Comment: still it dose not answer my question because am trying to do everything Dynamiclly , so what am thinking of is to update the class i built to create the form but if it has a relation to get the Field as a dropdown list to its original value from the other table

Comment: whats 'dynamically' in your case?

Comment: when i wont to create a to create a form for a table dynamically i created a class the check all the fields for a table from mysql and then i Generate the html fields , so i used the mysql statement "SHOW COLUMNS FROM TABLE" to get the fields but the array is not showing me any relations for any fields

Comment: use the SQL statement in my answer to obtain the foreign keys!
you can also `JOIN` the `SHOW COLUMNS` with the `SELECT`for the foreign keys